# Adding geometry from shapefile to dbf (one to many) Qgis

Tags: qgis, geometry, attribute-joins

Is there any possibility to add geometry from shapefile to dbf data in QGIS? Shapefile represents point localizations and has attribute with street, number and town. I have also dbf file where are people with the same attributes street, number and town where they live. I made key attributes for two files which concatenate these three attributes as a one. I want to add geometry from SHP to dbf that every person has his own location. Many people can live in the same place, so it is one to many relations. I use QGIS, or would Arcmap be better?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Werona! You could add a two new field using the **Field Calculator** to store the `X` and `Y` coordinates of the points. In QGIS, you can use the expression `$x` and `$y` to obtain the coordinates.